# Yubico SDK and FIDO Device

Tags: oauth, fido, yubico, yubikey

I'm writing a client application using yubico.Yubikey SDK in .Net. I'm trying to write a code which can fetch "FEITIAN" USB FIDO device connected to my laptop. Though Yubico and FEITIAN are two different companies, Still it shoul support protocol for FIDO standard.

Till now, I have tried following two methods, but both failed to get FEIIAN device.

1. IYubiKeyDevice yubiKeyDevice = YubiKeyDevice.FindByTransport(Transport.All).First();
2. var yubikeys = YubiKeyDevice.FindAll();

Please let me know if there's any another way.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure the .NET SDK is hard coded to only find devices with the Yubico brand device identifier.  The SDK is open source and can be found here: https://github.com/Yubico/Yubico.NET.SDK.